# com.google.android.play.core.install.InstallException: Install Error(-3): The API is not available on this device

Tags: android

```
E/com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.j: b
    com.google.android.play.core.install.InstallException: Install Error(-3): The API is not available on this device. (https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/install/model/InstallErrorCode#ERROR_API_NOT_AVAILABLE)
        at com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.j.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.play.core.internal.p.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.play.core.internal.j.onTransact(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
```

I'm getting this above error only for Android **Version 6**. I have kept `minSdkVersion` is **21** and `targetSdkVersion` is **28**. Do we have any solution for this error?

Comment: What is triggering this error?  Can you provide a [mre] that produces it?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, This bug kept me awake for nights. First I faced

**ERROR_INSTALL_NOT_ALLOWED**

The download/install is not allowed, due to the current device state (e.g. low battery, low disk space, ...).

Constant Value: -6 (0xfffffffa)

**Solution**
Ideal reasons could be a low battery, low disk space, etc but in my case, I was not logged on play store using my google account. If you are using emulator or actual device check if you are logged in on PlayStore

**ERROR_API_NOT_AVAILABLE**

The API is not available on this device.

Constant Value: -3 (0xfffffffd)
**Solution**

**1-** I was using the internal channel for in-app testing and update dialog was showing only on those devices on which my Gmail account was logged in on Play Store and was added to the internal channel. If your Gmail has not added, dialog will not be shown

**2-**
if you have uploaded the app for the public and tried to decrease version code for testing it will not be helpful. You will get Api not available. You should install app from Play Store and then increment version code and publish a new version. As soon as new version gets live, open the installed app. An update dialog will be shown.